# Is it possible to debug program while being executed?

Tags: linux, debugging, scripting, centos, monitoring

**Scenario:**

I executed a program (monitoring software) and it's taking so long to finish (almost 30 minutes right now). I know, by experience, that it should not take that long so I'm trying to find a way, if there's even one, to see what it's going on.

**What I tried:**

So far, the only things I managed to do is

```
ps auxww | grep myprogram
```

so I know it is working, and

```
tail -f myprogram.log
```

so I can see if somethings comes in the log. SO far, just some little warnings which won't, by any chance, interrupt the main program.

**Question:**

So, is there any way of, without restarting the program, `debug` it in any way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GNU debugger [gdb](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb) accepts option -p to attach to a runnig program. You have to know the PID of your process of course:

```
gdb -p PID
```